# Does ArcGIS Pro utilize response paging in their new wfs feature, and, if not, are there work-arounds?

Tags: wfs, arcgis-pro

ArcGIS Pro now has the ability to add a feature layer by WFS - however, it appears the functionality is limited in some respects based on the size of data requested.  Does anyone have knowledge of whether the WFS functionality in Pro uses WFS response paging, and, if not, if there are other known work-arounds for loading many features from an OGC WFS layer?

In ArcGIS Pro, there are two 'modes' for loading data, On Demand, and Snapshot.  On Demand mode loads only what is in the boundary, so you can scan around the map and see different features, and is not related to this question (unless someone knows how to easily build a layer off of such panning around).

Snapshot mode will load whatever you have set as the maximum features to return.  As stated in the documentation:

> "To avoid performance issues, the default value is set to 3000 features."

What I have found so far is you can load tens of thousands of features, or fewer than 3k, of course depending on the layer, specifically how much data is sent for the features (eg how many attributes).  ArcGIS 'fails silently' when some kind of limit is hit, and I am not able to determine what defines that limit:  it just won't display anything, and won't display an error message.  If you then lower the limit, it will display features again after a pause, if it will in fact display them.

Best for me would be to get response paging working, and that starts by knowing if Pro can even utilize response paging, and if so what arc-specific settings if any must be used there are to get it working.  Failing that, does anyone have work-arounds, or know of settings that can be changed to allow larger loads, or some way to see more information about the reason when a WFS fails to load or doesn't display data?

Comment: you can overide param MAXFEATURES. ref here:https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/latest/help/data/services/add-wfs-services.htm